# make axios request using variable with the state set in a previous request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

### Project Issues

- I'm having a problem using the state that was set, instead of the initial state where the values are empty.

### Description

- Im making an axios request and using the response to set the state.
- Im making another axios request that uses a parameter that I can only get after making the first request.
- When I try to reference the state that was set in the second request, it instead of using the set state it points back to the initial state.
- Therefore making the request fail
- from react dev tools

> State accountId: 47228906 name: "Senpai My Guy" summonerLevel: 127

### Code Snippet

initial state

---

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      summonerLevel: '',
      accountId: 0
    }
  }
```

first request

---

```
componentDidMount () {
    var api_key = '';

    axios
      .get(
        `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Senpai%20My%20Guy?api_key=${api_key}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.data.name)
        console.log(response.data.accountId)
        console.log(response.data.summonerLevel)

        this.setState({
          name: response.data.name,
          summonerLevel: response.data.summonerLevel,
          accountId: response.data.accountId
        })
        console.log(this.state.accountId)
      })
    var account_Id = this.state.accountId
```

---

add in the second one request

```
componentDidMount () {
    var api_key = '';

    axios
      .get(
        `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Senpai%20My%20Guy?api_key=${api_key}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data)
        console.log(response.data.name)
        console.log(response.data.accountId)
        console.log(response.data.summonerLevel)

        this.setState({
          name: response.data.name,
          summonerLevel: response.data.summonerLevel,
          accountId: response.data.accountId
        })
        console.log(this.state.accountId)
      })
    var account_Id = this.state.accountId
    axios
      .get(
        `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/${account_Id}?api_key=${api_key}`
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.matches)
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
```

---

### Error

```
GET https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/0?api_key= 404 (Not Found)
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

Comment: thanks, i just tried it out and it worked!

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so the state will not have been updated if you try to access it directly after using it. Your `axios` requests are also asynchronous, so you need to make sure the first request has finished before starting the second one.

You could instead use the `accountId` variable from the response in your second request.

**Example**

```
componentDidMount() {
  var api_key = "...";

  axios
    .get(
      `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Senpai%20My%20Guy?api_key=${api_key}`
    )
    .then(response => {
      var { name, summonerLevel, accountId } = response.data;

      this.setState({ name, summonerLevel, accountId });

      axios
        .get(
          `https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v3/matchlists/by-account/${accountId}?api_key=${api_key}`
        )
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data.matches);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
}
```